# Creating and Simple Class and Calling a Method from a cshtml File

Tags: razor, webmatrix

Could some one give a simple example of creating a simple class with a simple method and calling the method from cshtml file in webmatrix?

I am trying to figure out if WebMatrix could be used in an object oriented way that would allow me to take advantage of the razor sytax as a view engine alternative to the MVC framework that I could use in combination with webforms applications. Having the power and productivity of webforms on the back-end and razor on the public facing pages would be really awesome.

I have very limited knowledge of asp.net but WebMatrix intrigues me but I don't think the full inline approach is the right way to go.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just put a .cs file in App_Code with something like this...

```
public class Something {
    public void DoIt() {
    }
}
```

Then in a .cshtml file just call...

```
var something = new Something();
something.DoIt();
```

You could also just make it static and call Something.DoIt directly.

Hope that helps.