# Create a Simple Class and Call Its Method from a cshtml File without using App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have seen this related question [Creating and Simple Class and Calling a Method from a cshtml File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358633/creating-and-simple-class-and-calling-a-method-from-a-cshtml-file). How can we do that **without using the App_Code folder?**

In my project's root, I have a Something.cs class:

```
public class Something 
{
    public static void DoIt()  
    { 

    }
}
```

In my project's root, I also have index.cshtml with the following code:

```
@Something.DoIt()
```

The name `Something` does not exist in the current context of index.cshtml.

Comment: `@Something.DoIt()` means you are rendering something, so `DoIt()` method should have return value. By the way, where did you keep Something class?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to refer the projects library within the cshtml File

```
@using ProjectName;
```

Or refer to the object like this `@ProjectName.Something.DoIt()`

Comment: Can I do this on production. I mean add cs file on production

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing it on top of .cshtml or inside any HTML string template like for loop then

```
@{
   MvcDemo.Something.DoIt();
}
```

Inside BeginForm or the other then

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 MvcDemo.Something.DoIt();
}
```

Please Note MvcDemo is the namespace and if you direclty write `@MvcDemo.Something.DoIt()` you may get error.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I needed to take.

1. Create a file called SomeThing.cs.
2. Place said file anywhere in the csproj root directory.
3. Add said file to the .csproj **(this is what I forgot to do).**
4. Add class `SomeThing` with method `DoIt()` to said SomeThing.cs file.
5. Call its methods from SomeFile.cshtml file.

E.g. SomeFile.cshtml

```
@SomeThing.DoIt() // this assumes class SomeThing is NOT inside a namespace.
```

My problem was not adding SomeThing.cs to the .csproj.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I updated the answer to make it more complete.

Comment: @Ian I am the author of the question.